# Wordpress woocommerce Customization

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking for a way to print out the value of a product's custom field in the "order processing" that gets word count (" *how many word visitor type in field* ") then i can add tax base on words after they complete payment.

*like if words are 5 thats visitor type in text field. we charge 10$ per word. means 50$ for 5 words. ("not characters").*

i am using woocommerce plugin. and also woocommerce-product-addons.
woocommerce-product-addons pluging for add custom fields. **they have built in functionality to add custom price but its base on characters**. if i select max 100 words. they charge 10$ for 100 characters.

**i want to charge based on words.**

Comment: [link](http://cedarrustics.com/product/sample-product/)  you can see acttual look..

Comment: Maybe you can change the plugin? There's no way for us to give you any more detailed help without seeing some relevant code, though.